# jQuery: selecting 2 elements next to each other with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

here's my markup:

```
<button>next</button
<div class="seats">
  <div class="seat taken">1</div>
  <div class="seat taken">2</div>
  <div class="seat">3</div>
  <div class="seat">4</div>
  <div class="seat taken">5</div>
  <div class="seat">6</div>
  <div class="seat">7</div>
  <div class="seat taken">8</div>
  <div class="seat taken">9</div>
</div>
```

i'm looking for a way to select the first 2 free seats (which don't have class "taken"), given example should return seat 3+4.
would there be an easy way to have a variable amount of seats, eg. selecting 4 seats next to each other?
is it possible defining a offset where to start searching free seats? i mean i want to hit the next button and it should pick the next 2 free seats (6+7).
thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you to group them together in pairs, like in <div class="pair_of_seats"><div class="seat taken">1</div><div class="seat">2</div></div>. It would be easier to search for these groups and check if there is a seat not taken in one, as well as move to next group. But first, close the tag button correctly,  okay?

Comment: Also adding an ID to these groups would make it easier to take control of going back and forth.

Comment: Adding them to groups won't work, because you if you group chair 1 and 2 together, how are you going to check for chair 2 and 3 to be both untaken?

Comment: You won't. Not like that. I understand he wants to find the two first free seats TOGETHER, not otherwise. If the requisite is "any two seats with contiguous numbers", then thing must be thought again. What do you say @Fuxi?

Comment: "selecting 4 seats next to each other" and his two examples suggest that OP strictly wants chairs that are directly next to eachother, but I see the confusion now. Still, grouping chairs would not be easier than just walking over all chairs and storing the first two chairs that are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're allowed and able to add some more information to each chair: I'd extend your current html so that it'd look like this:

```
<button>next</button>
<div class="seats">
  <div class="seat taken" data-chairNumber="0">1</div>
  <div class="seat taken" data-chairNumber="1">2</div>
  <div class="seat" data-chairNumber="2">3</div>
  <div class="seat" data-chairNumber="3">4</div>
  <div class="seat taken" data-chairNumber="5">5</div>
  <div class="seat" data-chairNumber="6">6</div>
  <div class="seat" data-chairNumber="7">7</div>
  <div class="seat taken" data-chairNumber="8">8</div>
  <div class="seat taken" data-chairNumber="9">9</div>
</div>
```

Then use jQuery to only select the non taken chairs:

```
var chairs = $(".seat:not(.taken)");
```

Then walk over these chairs and check whether or not there exists a pair (probably extend this for bigger combinations):

```
var chairs = $(".seat:not(.taken)");
var currentChair = -2; //idunnkno
$.each(chairs, function(chair) {
    var chairnumber = $(chair).data("chairNumber");
    if(chairnumber - 1 === currentChair)
    {
         return { chairA : currentChair, chairB : chairNumber };
    }
    else {
         currentChair = chairnumber;
    }
});
```

Return an object with the chairs if you find a pair.

Comment: This is really hacky though, and you should probably refactor your code to where you're able to just ask a chair for it's neighbour: chair.adjacentChairs. Then recursively search for bigger combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and the methods [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), and [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) in order to achieve this in a single line:

```
$('.seat.taken + .seat:not(.taken)').eq(index).nextUntil('.taken').addBack()
```

It's also worth pointing out that this will work for groups of elements of varying lengths (not just groups of two elements).

**Explanation:**

- The initial query, `$('.seat.taken + .seat:not(.taken)')` will select `.seat` elements without a class of `.taken` that follow an element with the classes `.seat` and `.taken`.
- The `.eq(index)` method will reduce the set based on the `index` variable (where `index` denotes which group of available seats that you want to select).
- The `.nextUntil('.taken')` method will select all the following elements until another `.taken` element.
- Then the initial element is added back to the query with `.addBack()`.

**Basic example:**

```js
var index = 0;
$('.next').on('click', function () {
  $('.seat.taken + .seat:not(.taken)').eq(index).nextUntil('.taken').addBack().toggleClass('selected');
  
  index++;
});
```

```css
.selected { background-color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">next</button>
<div class="seats">
  <div class="seat taken">1</div>
  <div class="seat taken">2</div>
  <div class="seat">3 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">4  - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat taken">5</div>
  <div class="seat">6 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">7 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">8 - Not taken</div>
</div>
```

And if you want to cycle through the elements, you could create a basic function that returns a group of available seats based on the index:

```
function getNextGroup (index) {
  return $('.seat.taken + .seat:not(.taken)').eq(index).nextUntil('.taken').addBack();
}
```

Then you can call the function to determine if `index + 1` yields any elements. If it doesn't, then you would reset `index` back to `0` like in the example below:

**Updated example:**

```js
var index = 0;
$('.next').on('click', function () {  
  $('.seat.selected').removeClass('selected');
  getNextGroup(index).toggleClass('selected');
  
  index = getNextGroup(index + 1).length ? index + 1 : 0;
});

function getNextGroup (index) {
  return $('.seat.taken + .seat:not(.taken)').eq(index).nextUntil('.taken').addBack();
}
```

```css
.selected { background-color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">next</button>
<div class="seats">
  <div class="seat taken">1</div>
  <div class="seat taken">2</div>
  <div class="seat">3 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">4  - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat taken">5</div>
  <div class="seat">6 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">7 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">8 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat taken">9</div>
  <div class="seat taken">10</div>
  <div class="seat">11 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">12 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">13 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat">14 - Not taken</div>
  <div class="seat taken">15</div>
  <div class="seat">16 - Not taken</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and clean approach. Note: To be able to cycle through the elements you can reset the `index` if there are no further elements matched.