# cheerio - select two elements next to each other

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

How to select `a` elements but only when there are **two next to each other**?

```
<div>
 <a></a>     <---- without this one
 <irrelevant></irrelevant>
 <a></a>     <---- These two only
 <a></a>     <----
 <irrelevant></irrelevant>
 <a></a>     <---- and without these three
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
 <irrelevant></irrelevant>
 <a></a>     <---- and without this one 
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: This may help you get to where you need to be:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580859/jquery-selecting-2-elements-next-to-each-other-with-same-class  Instead of selecting by class name, select by tag name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about cheerio but in jQuery you can do this (although its hacky and horrible):

```js
$("div a").filter(function( index ) {
  var $this = $(this);
    return (
    $this.next("a").length>0 && //next is an a
    $this.next("a").next("a").length==0 &&  //next , next is not an a
    $this.prev("a").length==0 // prev is not an a
    ); 
  })
  .css( "background-color", "red" )
  .next("a")
  .css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <a>n</a> 
 <irrelevant></irrelevant>
 <a>y</a>
 <a>y</a>
 <irrelevant></irrelevant>
 <a>n</a>
 <a>n</a>
 <a>n</a>
 <irrelevant></irrelevant>
 <a>n</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually in jQuery you can just do: `$('a:has("+ a"):not(:has("+ a + a"))')` - that won't work in cheerio though.